# What works with RC2 quick release?

Tags: tripod-heads

A number of brands have quick-release systems that look like the RC2/200PL[image: illustration], but are they the same (intercompatible clones) or do they just *look* alike from a distance, down to the level with secondary locking pin?

Answer (score 1):

Only genuine Manfrotto RC2/200PL Quick Release plates and clamps will be fully compatible. The 3rd party tolerances are not close enough and there will be issues. Some will be close, but it has been my experience that the fit will be sloppy or possibly not fit at all.